# Execute a vim command after entering vim

Tags: vimrc

Is it possible to send a command to vim from the command-line? For example, to open the last file something like:

```
$ vim -e "`0"      # execute `0 after opening vim
```

Or, if I need to run a command, then:

```
$ vim -r ":normal!`0"
```

Is it possible to do this from the command-line before entering vim? When I tried running a normal `--cmd` arg I get:

```
$ vim --cmd "normal! \`0"
Error detected while processing pre-vimrc command line:
E20: Mark not set
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most concise:

```
$ vim +'norm! `0'
```

In Bash, [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html) imply that their contents will not be expanded. Since [backquotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) imply that their contents will be evaluated, enclosing the Ex command within single quotes ensures that Bash takes the backquote literally, so it won't be looking for a second backquote to terminate the first one.

Also, `vim +{command}` is the shorter equivalent to `vim -c {command}`, meaning you can replace one with the other. When opening vim, you can chain a maximum of 10 of either of them, in the form `vim +{command1} +{command2}...`

Lastly, if you wanted to run more than 10 Ex commands, you could also chain them with a bar in between, but there are [a few exceptions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#:%5Cbar). Below you can see the commands `:3d` and `:x` combined in one.

```
$ vim +"3d|x" fileName.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-c` option:

> -c {command} -- {command} will be executed after the first file has been
> read (and after autocommands and modelines for that file have
> been processed).  "command" is interpreted as an Ex command.
> If the "command" contains spaces, it must be enclosed in
> double quotes (this depends on the shell that is used).

And running it would be:

```
$ vim -c "normal! \`0"
```

Note the need to escape the `` ` `` in the command-line.

See [`:h -c`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-c) for more information.

Comment: Single quotes obviate the need for escaping.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks for that tip. Is there a link I can see as to using `"` and `'` in shell, and why with the later I wouldn't need to escape?

Comment: There are probably a few tutorials online around shell quoting; `man bash` is also good (there are sections on quoting). The gist of it is that single quotes stop all expansion, including backtick expansion, which is a legacy from of `$()` subshell expansion. Backticks are thus shell meta-characters and need quoted when used for being just a backtick